# How to open another activity after scanning a QR/bar code?

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am currently working on a QR code scanner. this code is running perfectly. I want to know how to open another activity after the QR code has been scanned? I have multiple activities. and I am using Zxing scanner for scanning purposes. below is my scanner file code:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    String scanResult = result.getText();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this::handleResult);
            //for error replace MainActivity.this
        }
    });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(scanResult));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setMessage(scanResult);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to call it normally regardless of whether it is the result of reading the QR code? [Start another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity), [How to Switch between Activities in Android](https://www.techbeamers.com/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/)

Comment: since i am new in android development so i don't know how to perform this. i store a text data in barcode, then after scanning if the store data is match then it goes to that particular activity

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not involved with Android. But in general, opening another activity would be independent(irrelevant) behavior of the barcode scanner or QRcode scan. Isn't the question valid even if the barcode-related information is deleted? Simply put, do you want to open another activity while one activity is running?

Comment: who says barcode information deleted. see after scanning the scanner is fetch a text data from barcode. then match the data and if the data is found then go the the next activity

Comment: That step is what you want to do in your application, not what you need to open other activities on Android. Isn't it possible to open other activities if there is some valid data, whether it is input from the keyboard or extracted from the website, not the result of scanning the barcode with a scanner? So you should learn how to open other activities purely without worrying about other conditions.